# Swipe to Delete Does not Show DeleteButtons in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am using the following code to add longPressGesture and also swipe to delete. But swipe to delete is not even showing the delete buttons. I think the gestures are colliding with each other.

```
ForEach(expenses) { expense in
    ExpenseCellView(expense: expense)
        .onLongPressGesture {
            // do something
        }
}.onDelete(perform: removeExpense) // delete buttons never show up when swiping
```

What can I do to solve this problem.

Comment: Because you are not encapsulating `ForEach` with `List`?